# Filipino with US green card traveling to Turkey with transit in Munich and Paris

Tags: transit, paris, filipino-citizens, munich

I am Filipino going to Istanbul. I will be applying for Turkey visa. One of the stopover from San Diego to Turkey is Paris CDG (waiting time 2 hours)  then on a different date after two weeks, i have to go to Brazil where my stopover is Munich, Germany. The waiting time in Munich is 40 minutes as per the itinerary. Do I need to apply for a Schengen visa or transit vîsa?

(Have to modify my statement for clarity)

Comment: Does GC means that you are a permanent US resident with a green card?

Comment: Yes GC is us permanent resident.

Comment: This is not the topic of your question, but the lengths of your layovers seem incredibly short.  Even without dealing with luggage, if you have to change terminals in Paris CDG (which is likely) it could take fully 2h, even if your plane landed exactly on time (rare, in my experience, for a flight that long).  As to 40mn in Munich, that might barely get you off the plane.  I'd revisit that itinerary if I were you..

Answer (score 1):

If you only have *one short layover* in the Schengen area per journey, you can generally transit without visa. In your case, it will be possible both in Paris and Munich. Filipino citizens don't need visas for airside transit in most Schengen countries, even without US green card. For some reason, the only Schengen country applying restrictions for airside transit is Hungary but in that case the US green card would still exempt you from the airport transit visa requirement, so you are fine in any case.

See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for a full explanation of the rules.

Comment: You're saying I must go to consulate or immigration office here in LA only to get schengen Visa for 2 hours in my i transit waiting inParis to Isyanbul. Then from Isyanbul to Brazil I have in transit in Munich.  The waiting. Time in Munich is 40 mins.  Does it mean in Paris, even if I only stop there for 2 hours in the airport to go fr next plane, I need a tourist visa?

Comment: If you only have one stop per journey (i.e. one stop in Paris on the way to Istanbul and one stop in Munich on the way back from Istanbul), it's completely different. I will adjust my answer.